# Pascal request from Android

Tags: java, android, pascal

I'm developing an application for manage security alarms and I have to work with the alarms API, an old code written in C#. The requests for disarm, arm...the alarms have to be done in Pascal (STDCALL) and I don't know how combine Android and Pascal.

Can anyone help me?

A lot of thanks.

Comment: Please explain what you mean with "pascal" and why you added the pascal language tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I know to execute Pascal code in Android is to compile a Free Pascal/Delphi shared library(.so) and access its interface through JNA/JNI. Of which two JNA seems to be the far less difficult option:

https://github.com/java-native-access/jna

You can't use Android's NDK tools to build such a native library as it is only C/C++. So you need to use an external compiler.

Comment: Free Pascal also has a JVM backend, though I don't know the exact status.

Comment: working with it, thanks man!